# Best way to perform select with where condition on joined tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance, join, search, lookup

I am currently building a search for my website and I'm struggling to come to a reasonable performance for my PostgreSQL query which seem simple on the surface.

Let's say I have two tables:

**orders (id, order_name, buyer, status) with 10M rows**

**products_purchased (id, order_id, product_reference) with 20M rows**

Let's say I'm now looking for the first 20 orders that included a specific product.

```
SELECT
  orders.id
FROM
  orders
INNER JOIN products_purchased ON products_purchased.order_id = orders.id
WHERE products_purchased.product_reference = 7
ORDER BY orders.id ASC
LIMIT 20
```

This query takes somewhere between 5 and 120 seconds.
Yet, I have all the proper indexes in places.

This seem to be because of the ORDER BY clause.

A problem will get just bigger as I add more products. For example, let's say I add a new product_reference in 1 year. If I perform a search to get the first 20 orders, it might take even longer because of the need to scan the entire table to find the first 2 orders.

What is the best practice to perform this kind of searches with large datasets?

Thank you a lot for your help!

--- Additional data ---

I have indexes where needed:

- orders.id
- products_purchased.order_id
- products_purchased.product_reference

The actual database size is:

- orders: 16M
- products_purchased: 20M

Selecting all orders having product_reference = 2000 for example takes 120 seconds despite the products_purchased table only having 46,000 occurence with product_reference=2000.

Execution plan below:

```
[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Node Type": "Limit",
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Startup Cost": 0.87,
      "Total Cost": 9846.45,
      "Plan Rows": 20,
      "Plan Width": 4,
      "Actual Startup Time": 59750.428,
      "Actual Total Time": 77196.124,
      "Actual Rows": 20,
      "Actual Loops": 1,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Nested Loop",
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Join Type": "Inner",
          "Startup Cost": 0.87,
          "Total Cost": 18802091.94,
          "Plan Rows": 38194,
          "Plan Width": 4,
          "Actual Startup Time": 59750.426,
          "Actual Total Time": 77196.101,
          "Actual Rows": 20,
          "Actual Loops": 1,
          "Inner Unique": true,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Node Type": "Index Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Scan Direction": "Forward",
              "Index Name": "products_purchased_order_id_idx",
              "Relation Name": "products_purchased",
              "Alias": "products",
              "Startup Cost": 0.44,
              "Total Cost": 18746328.16,
              "Plan Rows": 38194,
              "Plan Width": 4,
              "Actual Startup Time": 59746.776,
              "Actual Total Time": 77171.904,
              "Actual Rows": 20,
              "Actual Loops": 1,
              "Filter": "(product_reference = 2000)",
              "Rows Removed by Filter": 514614
            },
            {
              "Node Type": "Index Only Scan",
              "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Scan Direction": "Forward",
              "Index Name": "orders_pkey",
              "Relation Name": "orders",
              "Alias": "orders",
              "Startup Cost": 0.43,
              "Total Cost": 1.46,
              "Plan Rows": 1,
              "Plan Width": 4,
              "Actual Startup Time": 1.197,
              "Actual Total Time": 1.197,
              "Actual Rows": 1,
              "Actual Loops": 20,
              "Index Cond": "(id = products_purchased.order_id)",
              "Rows Removed by Index Recheck": 0,
              "Heap Fetches": 10
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "Planning Time": 7.893,
    "Triggers": [
    ],
    "Execution Time": 77196.878
  }
]
```

Comment: What does the execution plan look like? A possible cause for a delay is that the join columns and `product_reference` aren't very selective. Given that the only criteria here is `product_reference = 7`, this could cover half of all records, or 1/10. There's no way to improve that - a human would still have to scan all records to find which ones match, which ones to exclude. What does `First 20` mean, based on what ordering? Perhaps you can add extra filtering conditions to reduce the number of matching rows

Comment: Thank. Yes it was a typo. Edited :).
I have all the indexed needed in particular on orders.id, products_purchased.order_id and products_purchased.product_reference

Comment: But the only filter condition doesn't seem to be very selective, which means the server still has to scan a lot of index rows to find matches

Comment: please share the execution plan: `explain analyze select ...`

Comment: Selecting all orders having product_reference = 2000 for example takes 120 seconds despite the products_purchased table only having 46,000 occurence with product_reference=46,000.
Running the verbose now.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev just added the execution plan.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask]

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your setup by genearing 10M random orders and 16M random purchases and the query is executed for 0.5s on my machine :) With a semi-join the query time is reduced to 50 milliseconds :) Which version of postgres are you using ?

Comment: Please use text format for the execution plan.  JSON is easy to read for machines, but hard for humans.

Comment: Why even join to `orders`?  It looks like you are only using it for one column, and that column is also available in the other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your issue but I could not get the high times you are reporting. I guess my data distribution does not match yours, but still the difference is too big.

My setup:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";


create table orders
(
    id         serial not null,
    order_name text   not null,

    constraint orders_pkey primary key (id)
);

create table products_purchased
(
    id                serial  not null,
    order_id          integer not null,
    product_reference integer not null,


    constraint products_purchased_fkey_order foreign key (order_id) references orders (id)
);

alter sequence orders_id_seq cache 100000;
alter sequence products_purchased_id_seq cache 100000;

insert into orders(order_name)
select uuid_generate_v4()
from generate_series(1, 16000000);

insert into products_purchased(order_id, product_reference)
select random() * 15999999 + 1, random() * 10000 + 1
from generate_series(1, 20000000);

alter sequence orders_id_seq cache 1;
alter sequence products_purchased_id_seq cache 1;

create index products_purchased_order_id on products_purchased using btree (order_id);
create index products_purchased_product_ref on products_purchased using btree (product_reference);

vacuum analyse;
```

Also given that you want the first N orders which include a specific product, you need to select the *DISTINCT* order ids, otherwise you may get duplicate orders.

## Baseline (the results for your query):

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.id
FROM orders o
         INNER JOIN products_purchased p ON p.order_id = o.id
WHERE p.product_reference = 2000
ORDER BY o.id ASC
LIMIT 20;
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=1000.90..9677.24 rows=20 width=4) (actual time=184.548..424.877 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  Unique  (cost=1000.90..866032.55 rows=1994 width=4) (actual time=184.547..424.868 rows=20 loops=1)
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1000.90..866027.56 rows=1994 width=4) (actual time=184.546..424.837 rows=20 loops=1)
               ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.46..857325.28 rows=1994 width=4) (actual time=184.491..463.432 rows=20 loops=1)
                     Workers Planned: 2
                     Workers Launched: 2
                     ->  Parallel Index Scan using products_purchased_order_id on products_purchased p  (cost=0.44..856095.10 rows=831 width=4) (actual time=70.818..334.005 rows=8 loops=3)
                           Filter: (product_reference = 2000)
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 65639
               ->  Index Only Scan using orders_pkey on orders o  (cost=0.43..4.36 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=1 loops=20)
                     Index Cond: (id = p.order_id)
                     Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.408 ms
 Execution Time: 463.962 ms
(14 rows)
```

## Assuming you cannot modify the indexes

Then you can use a semi-join, which at least on my DB gives a 10x increase in speed:

```
SELECT o.id
FROM orders o
WHERE exists(SELECT 1 FROM products_purchased p WHERE p.product_reference = 2000 AND p.order_id = o.id)
ORDER BY o.id ASC
LIMIT 20;
```

```
                                                                              QUERY PLAN                                                                              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=8288.94..11689.62 rows=20 width=4) (actual time=23.580..39.330 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  Gather Merge  (cost=8288.94..347337.07 rows=1994 width=4) (actual time=23.579..43.328 rows=20 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         ->  Merge Semi Join  (cost=7288.91..346106.89 rows=831 width=4) (actual time=13.660..28.522 rows=8 loops=3)
               Merge Cond: (o.id = p.order_id)
               ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using orders_pkey on orders o  (cost=0.43..322155.39 rows=6666680 width=4) (actual time=0.071..10.471 rows=52366 loops=3)
                     Heap Fetches: 0
               ->  Sort  (cost=7276.79..7281.77 rows=1994 width=4) (actual time=12.096..12.103 rows=23 loops=3)
                     Sort Key: p.order_id
                     Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 194kB
                     Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 194kB
                     Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 194kB
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on products_purchased p  (cost=40.02..7167.50 rows=1994 width=4) (actual time=1.618..10.885 rows=2074 loops=3)
                           Recheck Cond: (product_reference = 2000)
                           Heap Blocks: exact=2053
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on products_purchased_product_ref  (cost=0.00..39.52 rows=1994 width=0) (actual time=1.100..1.100 rows=2074 loops=3)
                                 Index Cond: (product_reference = 2000)
 Planning Time: 0.759 ms
 Execution Time: 43.426 ms
(20 rows)

Time: 44.853 ms
```

## **But If you can modify the index though, you can create much more optimal index:**

```
create index products_purchased_idx on products_purchased using btree(product_reference, order_id);
```

Then your original query will run even faster than the semi join:

```
                                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                                                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.87..88.79 rows=20 width=4) (actual time=0.109..0.291 rows=20 loops=1)
   ->  Unique  (cost=0.87..8766.60 rows=1994 width=4) (actual time=0.107..0.284 rows=20 loops=1)
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.87..8761.62 rows=1994 width=4) (actual time=0.105..0.266 rows=20 loops=1)
               ->  Index Only Scan using products_purchased_idx on products_purchased p  (cost=0.44..59.33 rows=1994 width=4) (actual time=0.089..0.106 rows=20 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (product_reference = 2000)
                     Heap Fetches: 0
               ->  Index Only Scan using orders_pkey on orders o  (cost=0.43..4.36 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=20)
                     Index Cond: (id = p.order_id)
                     Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.536 ms
 Execution Time: 0.365 ms
(11 rows)

Time: 1.368 ms
```

~0.4 milliseconds of execution time vs the ~464 ms with the old indexes, which is ~1100x speedup :)

Comment: Hey Svetlin. That's a fantastic answer. Thank you a lot for your time.

The semi join solution didn't work.
However the double index worked.
I went from 100sec to 0.5sec.

Awesome!